# UnitTest SSIS (VS2008) with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, ssis

I have a SSIS 2008 project and would like to write UnitTests for individual packages with VS2010. The reason for this is that we have a VS2010 Db project with stored procedures, functions, ect. which already has a good amount of db unit tests. I'd like to be able to test the SSIS packages in the same project.

I know that it is not possible to edit or even open SSIS 2008 projects with VS2010. However for our UnitTests it is safe to assume the last version of the SSIS packages have already been deployed.

What i would like to do is the following:

- Check for the existence of a package (fail test if its not available)
- Execute the package
- Verify its results

I know that it is not optimal that the project is split in two projects, unfortunatly using Denali is not an option right now.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to write standard MSTest Unit Tests with VS2010. Using the managed SSIS object model i can do whatever i need, so thats a good fit for my reqs.

The assembly can be found here:
:\\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll

Answer (score 0):

I only had a very brief look at ssisUnit a while back but you should definitely check it out.

http://ssisunit.codeplex.com/

Comment: is a separate tool, not in vs2010